# Raspberry PI as online radio client with Mplayer

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, mplayer

Long story short I have created online radio for my client and now I need to create client nodes for the radio. I decided to use Raspberry pi, because its perfect for the job. I installed raspberrian lite and I decided to use Mplayer as media player.

So I created simple python3 script, that will run my mplayer when there is internet connection.

I am no python developer, but this seems to work pretty well, until something happens and there is no sound comming out of the PI. I assume my pi runs out of cache and tries to do something, but It fails.

To run my script I use `rc.local`

What I need is reliable radio client, that I can replicate, install and never ever gave a sh*t about it.

Command for running mplayer: `mplayer -cache 16384 -cache-min 80 http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8000/stream`

**UPDATE#1**:When I start mplayer manually it runs fine, just as it runs with that python script. The trouble happens during day/night, when it unexpectedly stops streaming the music. I'll give more details once it stops working again.

**UPDATE#2**: So the raspberry pi stopped responding again. I have no HDMI output and when I try connecting via SSH I get `kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset`. Pi is not responding to anything other than hard reset. LAN LEDs are blinking and the ACT LED blinks too although softly (2% of brightness). I am starting to think, that I have faulty PI.

**UPDATE#3**: Raspberry gave me this error: `Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jul  8 13:46:10 ... kernel:[  587.522492] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents -- potential data loss!  (inode 45281, error -30)` The system is fresh I installed it yesterday via `raspberry imager app`. Could it be my mini sd card ?

Comment: The python side of this is off topic here. We can focus on mplayer but you would have to give some indication of what errors you get and what actually happens. So far you've just said "something happens and there is no sound" which doesn't really say much. Run mplayer manually, does it give any errors? Please [edit] your question to remove the python side and add in any relevant details.

Comment: MicroSD cards are indeed prone to failure, at the very least you should get a new SD card to make sure your old one isn't dying. It definitely sounds like some filesystem failure is happening.